# Append items to a list in python at spaced intervals

Tags: python, list, append, intervals

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to append items from one list to another at spaced intervals. My code so far is:

```
def place_item(a,b):
    interval = (4,8)
    for s in a:
        i = a.index(s)
        b[i:i] = [s]
    print b

a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

b = [''] * (3*26)

place_item(a,b)
```

The result I get is the first 26 letters followed by 52 ' ' spaces within a list, which makes sense since I haven't asked it to produce "list a" more than once or to place the items in "list a" at at intervals between 4 and 8 spaces after the preceding list.
 So basically I'm trying to loop over "list a" and intersperse its letters throughout "list b" 4 and 8 spaces apart. And I have no idea how to do this :(. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'll include what everyone pointed out to me that I forgot. I want the spaces between items to be anywhere between 4 to 8 characters long, a length which is randomly chosen for each item. The result would look something like this:

```
['a','','','','','','b','','','','','','','c','','','','','d'...]
```

EDIT 2: blob8108 pointed out that I'd quickly run out of space using this method. Would it be possible to have some letters go in normal sequence ('a','b','c','d',etc.) and have other letters space out from those initial letters (e.g. 'e','f','g' go 4-8 spaces from 'a', while 'h','i','j' go 4-8 spaces from 'b')? The result might look like this:

```
['a','b','c','d','g','e','h','i',etc.]
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? How do you plan to use this function?

Comment: are you asking for every 4th or 8th letter to be put into list b

Comment: Wouldn't every 8th letter _by definition_ also be a 4th letter? 8 / 4 = 2

Comment: If this is homework, make sure to tag it as such.

Comment: This is an incredibly simple version of a larger experiment I want to run using python. In the experiment, I want trials (which are simply dicts) to be placed throughout a block (a list of dicts). The letters here represent the trials. I first want to figure out how to append items, whether they be dicts, lists of dicts, or simply strings, to a new list and place them within that list at positions 4 to 8 spaces apart. Sorry about the poor description :(.

Comment: When you say "4 to 8 spaces", do you mean somewhere in that range, chosen randomly for each item?

Comment: I think you could clear up a lot of confusion if you showed us what you want the result to look like for your given inputs.

Comment: Ah sorry. Here's what I want my result to look like: ['a','','','','','b','','','','','','','','','c','','','','','','d'...etc.]. Again, sorry if I'm not being very clear. I'm really new to this.

Comment: That's a perfect description blob8108. The spaces need to be somewhere between 4 to 8 spaces long and chosen randomly for each item.

Comment: Does the output list have to be a fixed length (3*26 in your example), or can it vary each time?

Comment: I'd like to keep it at a fixed length if possible.

Comment: So what happens if you run out of space?

Comment: I see what you mean. How could I make the length vary?

Comment: Would it be possible to have some letters appear in sequence ('a','b','c','d',etc.) and have the other letters separate out from them using the intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import random

abc = [chr(x) for x in range(97, 123)]
out = []

out.append(abc[0])
for item in abc[1:]:
    out += [''] * random.randrange(4, 8)
    out.append(item)
```

This does have variable-length output, though.

You'll have to explain more how fixed length would work if that's what you want.

Comment: I switched to a variable-length output, used this algorithm, and it worked :). Thank you so much man and sorry for bogging you down with my inexperience.

Comment: It's fine. I'm glad it helped :)